# Android studio debbuger always step on last catch block even not exceptions

Tags: java, android-studio, exception, try-catch

I have this class:

```
public class ConnectionInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response;
        try {
            response = chain.proceed(request);
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            throw new IOException("Ошибка соединения с сервером");
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            throw new IOException("Время ожидания соединения истекло");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }

        if (response.code() == 500) {
            throw new ApiNfpException("Ошибка с кодом 500");
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

When I get success response (status 200) in debug mode, I see some strange behavior in Android Studio. The debugger stops on the last catch block.

Step 1: I have set many breakpoints. I send a request to server and get response. I stop on this line:

[image]

Step 2: I check the error:

[image]

Step 3: I press F9 button and move to next line:

[image]

If I remove the third catch block, I stop on the second block. Why does the debugger stop on the catch block if there is seemingly no error?

Comment: When it's entering the last catch block, is it printing the error message in the log?

Comment: @riadrifai  no does not print. because there is no error. and does not stop at the line where it should be typing.

Comment: Did you try to clear cache and restart android studio?

Comment: @riadrifai yes of course